# How can I work around Type.IsAssignableFrom not working with inherited interfaces?

Tags: c#

I've made a test case to illustrate the problem I've run into.

The first assert passes, but the second and third both fail.

Is there a way to check either of the two failing conditions k in a different way that will work? It would be OK if it's not terribly fast as I intend to cache the results on a per-type basis.

```
public interface IParentInterface
{

}

public interface IChildInterface : IParentInterface
{

}

public class ParentClass<T> where T: IParentInterface
{

}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass<IChildInterface>
{

}

public class TestClass
{
    public ChildClass Property { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ScratchPad
{

    [Test]
    public void Assignabl()
    {
        var tc = new TestClass();
        var tct = tc.GetType();

        var pi = tct.GetProperty("Property");

        Assert.IsNotNull(pi);

        Assert.IsTrue(typeof(ParentClass<IChildInterface>).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType));
        Assert.IsTrue(typeof(ParentClass<>).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType));
        Assert.IsTrue(typeof(ParentClass<IParentInterface>).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is by design that your second assertion fails. When you write

```
public class ParentClass<ParentInterface>
```

it actually means that "ParentInterface" is now a symbol for a type argument (doing that is so confusing that, indeed, it totally confused you).
Writing

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass<ChildInterface>
```

then sets yout type argument (yeah, the one named "ParentInterface") to the type ChildInterface. Hence, Childclass is only assignable to ParentClass<ChildInterface>.

Lastly, you should ensure that you follow conventions when definining type arguments, it will confuse you a lot less, e.g.

```
public class ParentClass<T>
```

marking interfaces with "I" will also greatly enhance understanding, e.g.

```
interface IParent { }
interface IChild : IParent { }
```

I suspect that that which you want is not possible until we get c# 4.0:

```
Parent<IChild>
```

is not assignable to

```
Parent<IParent>
```

There is currently no co/contravariance for generics.

Comment: I made a mistake making the test case, that wasn't representative of the actual situation. I've edited the example to reflect this.

Comment: C# 4.0 will have covariance for generics with the 'out' keyword.

Comment: Oh well. I think I'll be able to do what I need with reflection, it just feels so much dirtier than what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this [the covariance/contravariance thing](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=282003)?

Then it's just something C# currently does not support, but C# 4.0 might.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because C# 3.0 does not support variance of this kind.  In C# 4.0, you should be able to.

Using another example, say you had a `List<ParentInterface>`, and *could* assign it to a `List<ChildInterface>`:

```
List<ParentInterface> parentList = List<ParentInterface>();
List<ChildInterface> childList = parentList;
```

The problem is that the internal storage for `parentList` is for `ParentInterface` types.  If you derived another interface from `ChildInterface`:

```
public interface ParentInterface2 : ChildInterface {}
```

And then tried to add it to `childList` like so:

```
childList.Add(new ParentInterface2Implementation());
```

You would get an exception, since `childList` is really a `List<ParentInterface>` and can only store implementations of `ParentInterface`, which `ParentInterface2` is not.